# Parallax effect for 300px tall footer only?

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I am wanting to reveal a footer behind the rest of the content, but the issue I am having is that my website continues scrolling for the entire screen, rather than just the 300px height of the footer. Here is what I have so far:

http://everetdale.com/starfalling.ca/

As you can see the footer is revealed, but so is lots of white space above it. Here is a website that does what I want to do:

http://ideaware.co/

How can I make it so that the scrolling stops once the footer is revealed?

Answer (score 1):

/*** Updated Answer based on Comments ***/

Since nothing else will move and only the background images will "reveal" for a parallax type effect, I suggest this with only HTML/CSS which can be demo'd here:

http://jsfiddle.net/VyQdY/

HTML Code:

```
<div id="one">
     <p> Lorem ipsum and other text. Lorem ipsum and other text. Lorem ipsum and other text. Lorem ipsum and other text. Lorem ipsum and other text. Lorem ipsum and other text. </p>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <p> Two Lorem ipsum and other text. Lorem ipsum and other text. Lorem ipsum and other text. Lorem ipsum and other text. Lorem ipsum and other text. Lorem ipsum and other text.     </p>
</div>
<div id="three">
    <p> And finally three Lorem ipsum and other text. Lorem ipsum and other text. Lorem ipsum and other text. Lorem ipsum and other text. Lorem ipsum and other text. Lorem ipsum and other text. </p>
</div>
```

And the respective CSS:

```
#one, #two, #three {height: 600px; width:100%;}

#one {background: url(http://placekitten.com/600/800) top center fixed;}
#two {background: url(http://placekitten.com/700/800) center center fixed;}
#three {background: url(http://placekitten.com/600/850) top center fixed;}
```

​
​

(*Please excuse the placeholder kittens for background images*, **I don't even like kittens**)

/*** Original Answer ***/

Without knowing more or seeing your code, I can tell the problem has to do with the height of your entire page (perhaps the div above the footer).

You need to make sure the height is at a point that "stops scrolling" when it reaches the top of your footer.

If you paste your code into jsfiddle I could help explain more (or even demonstrate).

Also, it seems you are using javascript to do some of this - are you planning on having different background and images move at different times when scrolling or will everything be "static" and only "reveal" when scrolled? If so you can accomplish all of this with just HTML & CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not planning on having things move at different times when scrolling, it will be static, and a pure CSS solution would be ideal for me. I would be very grateful if you could point me in the right direction to achieve that.

Comment: The line of code with  <li id="section-1" class="cover current" style="height: 617px; z-index: 999;" data-height="617" data-position="0">
<article>  is having the problem

Comment: This article will help with your sticky footer "revealing" http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/ - they just do it the opposite - it's always visible, you would just need to put the z-index of the footer less than the rest of the content. And you can achieve the "reveal" effect with multiple divs by using background: fixed css.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript calculates the combined heights of the two main ol>li and uses the function setBodyHeight() to set the body height. since your content in the top li (#section-1) is MUCH higher this calculation fail. You should start checking this...

Answer (score 0):

I have read through your source code, and I can see that you have an `li` element that containers what I assume the main content. Now this element is dynamically changing it's `margin-top` CSS rule from 0 to about 600. I wonder if this is your problem, because as you scroll down, this element is forced to go very high up due to this `margin-top` changing.

I cannot accurately find your problem because I have not used `curtain.js` before, but maybe try looking into why your element is gaining such a high `margin-top` and see if you can remove this.

I hope this helped!

Comment: I wasnt able to find what you are referring to. Is the "footer" the element that is having its margin-top changed? Are you able to determine code in the curtains.js file which causes this? Is there a different jquery plugin which would work better for this?